# css for jquery popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Somebody please explain why this

```
$('#errmsgDiv')
    .html("<br/><p>"+msg+"</p><br/>")
    .css("background-color","pink")
    .popup('open', {positionTo: $(errInput)});
```

or this

```
$('#errmsgDiv')
    .html("<br/><p>"+msg+"</p><br/>")
    .popup('open', {positionTo: $(errInput)})
    .css("background-color","pink");
```

doesn't give my popup a pink background?

I initiate the popup with

```
$('#errmsgDiv').popup();
```

and my div looks like this:

```
<div id="errmsgDiv" data-role="popup"><p>msg text</p></div>
```

Comment: it's working http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/83qTy/

Comment: Thanks Omar. Didn't work in jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1 but did in jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2. You made the point the other day :-(

Comment: Ok I'll check it on 1.3

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vEDVm/ 1.3

Comment: I didn't think that was the issue to be honest so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for me. Anyway I'm now on 1.4.2 so it's no longer an issue. Thank you again for your help